# Obtener muchas variables apartir de un SELECT en un TRIGGER en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Lo que pasa es que tengo un  TRIGGER asi:

```
DELIMITER |

    CREATE TRIGGER actividad_tablero 
    AFTER INSERT ON project_manager.tareas_tablero 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE nombre_user VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE nombre_tablero VARCHAR(00);
    SET nombre_user = 
    (SELECT 
    u.nombre 
    FROM tablero t 
    INNER JOIN tareas_tablero tt ON t.id_tablero = tt.id_tablero 
    INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = t.id_usuario WHERE t.tablero = New.id_tablero);
SET nombre_tablero = 
(SELECT 
t.nombre_tablero 
FROM tablero t 
INNER JOIN tareas_tablero tt ON t.id_tablero = tt.id_tablero 
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = t.id_usuario WHERE t.tablero = New.id_tablero);
INSERT INTO actividad 
    SET 
        id_usuario = NEW.id_usuario, 
        tipo_actividad = 'Tablero Agregado',
        fecha = Now(),
        descripcion = concat_ws(' ' ,'El usuario ' , nombre_user , ' agrego una tarea ' , New.titulo_tarea , ' al tablero ' , nombre_tablero , ' el ' , Now());
  END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Como pueden ver declaro dos variables [nombre_user] y [nombre_tablero], en las cuales guardo un valor a partir de un SELECT, el problema es que con ese mismo SELECT puedo obtener ambas variables, la pregunta es...¿como puedo evitar hacer dos consultas, y obtener las dos variables con un solo SELECT?

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita y coloca el código como texto

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que para esto, podrías usar la sintaxis de [`select .. into`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), por ejemplo:

```
SELECT u.nombre, t.nombre_tablero
       INTO nombre_tablero, nombre_user
       FROM tablero t 
       INNER JOIN tareas_tablero tt ON t.id_tablero = tt.id_tablero 
       INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = t.id_usuario WHERE t.tablero = New.id_tablero;
```